# FBLoginView background image tiling (not resizing properly)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Having a weird issue with FBLoginView, basically it doesn't resize properly and ends up either stretching or tiling

It was working fine on the previous version of my app, now that I'm coming to release a new update I've noticed it starts tiling the background image and generally not sizing as it should do?

I've downloaded the latest version of the iOS SDK, tried integrating by Cocoapods and now just the normal .pkg install

I'm using this code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"]];

loginView.delegate = self;

loginView.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 247.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"]];
```

loginView.delegate = self;

loginView.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 247.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[self.view addSubview:loginView];

but achieving the result below which clearly isn't supposed to happen! Can't find any reference to it online and not sure why it would happen as I'm not doing anything unusual?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the [loginView sizeToFit]; method to get rid of the view clipping.